# get last 30 days DATES dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I building an chart to display of Sales made in last 30 days.
I m getting output & other stuff for chart, but how do get dates for the label/legend/title? That too the date(label/legend title) changes everyday as i display data of last 30days. So i m looking to get output as dates of last 30 days.

If Current Date: 13-NOV-2019 
Output example:

12-OCT-2019
13-OCT-2019
14-OCT-2019
...
...
...
12-NOV-2019

Comment: What kind of monster in 2019 uses *two digit years*? Did Y2K teach us nothing? Maybe that last one is November 12th, 2019. Or possibly November 19th, 2012.

Comment: @tadman Or December 11th 2019

Comment: @GrumpysaysReinstateMonica It's great when you get food labelled like this and you're not sure if it's still good, or is from seven years ago.

Comment: sorry about confusion. Dates meant in dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: @tadman though format i mentioned on subject.

Comment: Note the relational databases are for the storage and retrieval of relational data, and not much else.

Comment: Date formatting is usually something you do in the application layer where you can take into account locale considerations, user preferences and such. MySQL should store them in [ISO 8601 format, `YYYY-MM-DD`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) for consistency's sake.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE start_date BETWEEN DATE(NOW()) AND DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 30 DAY)`

Comment: getting data from table i knew this trick. but i dont need data from table. i just need dates of last 30days.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is

```
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(@Date + Interval tr1.addd  Day,'%d-%b-%Y')
FROM (SELECT @date := '2019-10-01') td
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 addd UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5
UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10) tr1
```

This would give You

```
01-Oct-2019
02-Oct-2019
03-Oct-2019
04-Oct-2019
05-Oct-2019
06-Oct-2019
07-Oct-2019
08-Oct-2019
09-Oct-2019
10-Oct-2019
11-Oct-2019
```

With mysql 8.x
You can use CTE to generate the addays

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT 1 AS n
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n + 1 FROM cte WHERE n < 10
)
SELECT n FROM cte
```

Which would gove you

```
n
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```